# How can I send a JSON body with AsyncHttpClient?

Tags: java, android, json, post, asynchttpclient

I'm using [AsyncHttpClient](http://loopj.com/android-async-http/) library to make HTTP requests from a very basic Android app. For now, I just need to make a **POST** request with a **JSON** body (and that's a mandatory constraint, since the **REST** services I have to use expect a request in that format) containing a username and a password.

Not knowing much about Android development and the library in question I tried to make a simple **GET** request to Google, and it perfectly worked. Then, I tried to switch to a **POST** request but it seems from the documentation that the post method needs strictly a *RequestParams* parameter.
I really need to send a **JSON**: is there a way to do so with `AsyncHttpClient`? I tried several solutions found both on the web and on StackOverflow, but unfortunately no one worked.

Ultimately, as a last chance, I'm willing to switch library (and suggestions in this direction would be welcome, too - at least if they're easy-to-use as `AsyncHttpClient` is, considering my inexperience), but I would prefer to stick to my current choice.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

first, i suggest u to use retrofit library, it's simple, useful and sweet
but for now, we should to know that how do you do your post,
for example, do you test this:

```
private static AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
RequestParams params = new RequestParams();
params.put("param1", "Test"); 
client.post(Url, params, responseHandler);
JSONObject jsonParams = new JSONObject();
jsonParams.put("param1", "Test");
StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(jsonParams.toString());
client.post(context, Url, entity, "application/json",responseHandler);
```

Comment: Your solution is very close to the one I finally adopted and which worked. Anyway, for this to work, is essential the inclusion of *cz.msebera.android.httpclient.entity.StringEntity*: if you import StringEntity from another library it won't match the signature of the post method declared by AsyncHttpClient (this was the reason why it didn't work for me).